# Run React-App Build on ASP.NET Core 7 WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, create-react-app, asp.net-core-7.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 7 WebAPI with many routes like:

- domain.com/Api/Product/GetAll
- domain.com/Api/Product/Delete/
- domain.com/Api/Product/Create
- ...

and I have a react-app which i need to use its build folder running on my ASP server like:

- domain.com/my-react-app

I mean I want to use my ASP as react-app Server, how can i do this?

my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;

string WEB_ROOT_PATH = "Images";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(
    new WebApplicationOptions { WebRootPath = WEB_ROOT_PATH }
);

string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(
        name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        }
    );
});

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.MapGet("/", () => "ok");
app.MapGet("/CheckLocalServer", () => "ok");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(
    new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "Images")
        ),
        RequestPath = "/Upload"
    }
);
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

my Packages:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi" Version="7.0.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.14">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.14" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Sync\NewFolder\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After publish the webapi to folder, create a new folder "wwwroot" in the root directory.
After publish the react app "npm run build" Copy all the published files to the "wwwroot" folder.
[image]
Then run the published webapplication.exe, you could visit api and react pages in the same port.
Test with "create-react-app" template and "dotnet new webapi" template (add `app.UseStaticFiles();`):
[image]